# Django update a field using query of the other table

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have four models like below:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class BranchItem(models.Model):
    branch = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item,
                             blank=False,
                             null=False)

class TaxItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, blank=False, null=False)
    tax = models.ForeginKey(Tax, blank=False, null=False)
    tax_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                blank=True,
                                default='PE')
    amount = models.FloatField(default=9, blank=True)

class SellItem(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0.0)
    branch_item = models.ForeignKey(BranchItem, blank=Flase, null=False)
    tax = model.ForeignKey(TaxItem, blank=False, null=False)
```

Now I want to update all `SellItem`with appropriate tax which must get from `TaxItem` table, the `SellItem` table is huge and I do not want to update each row saparetly in python and it must do completely in database side.

The main problem I encountered is what I said above but as a solution I choose update method using a `Subquery` as is shown in below code:

```
tax_query = TaxItem.objects.filter(item_id=OuterRef('item')).values_list('id')

try:
 SellItem.objects.annotate(item=F('branch_item__item')).update(tax_id=Subquery(tax_query[:1]))
finally:
    connection.queries
```

It generates an insane query like below:

```
UPDATE "api_sellitem" SET "tax_id" = (
 SELECT
 U0."id"
 FROM
 "api_taxitem" U0
 WHERE
 U0."item_id" = ("api_branchitem"."item_id")
 LIMIT
 1)
 WHERE
 "api_sellitem"."id" IN (
 SELECT
 V0."id" AS Col1
 FROM
 "api_sellitem" V0
 INNER JOIN
 "api_branchitem" V1 ON (V0."branch_item_id" = V1."id"))
```

Which is obviously wrong and I could not figure how could I correct this?

I am using django 1.11.3 and postgresql as database, Please give me a suggestion for solving the main problem i.e. updating a table using query in another table or the second one i.e. the problem I encountered in using update and subquery method together.

Comment: I dont understand how you want to update the SellItem's tax ! Which sellitem will get which taxitem ? I did not get the logic with which you assign tax to sellitem

Comment: `with appropriate tax` - and which is that for any `SellItem`? You have no links between TaxItem and Item/BranchItem. The only TaxItem you could obtain by query is "TOP 1"-like.

Comment: This is not the complete model that I am using, there is a `end_time` field for tax which shows it is finished in a certain time, I want to keep history of tax and the `TaxItem` table is for this manner. Now I can fetch tax for each item and choose the last one as @IvanStarostin mentioned.

Comment: A query for update sell item can be this, `sellitem.tax = TaxItem.objects.get(item=sellitem.branch_item.item)[0]`

Comment: @IvanStarostin I modify models, there was a typo error in it, `TaxItem` is a many to many table between `Tax` and `Item`